# Facebook/Twitter Style photos grid style layout

Tags: css, angularjs, facebook, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm trying to implement a facebook style photos grid layout. I'm using angularjs and bootstrap for this. I have come across certain plugins like [angular-masonry](https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry) which I think can be used for this. Following are some snapshots of what I'm actually trying to achieve following possible layouts:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any idea how can this be achieved ? Is there any other plugin which can make life easy ?

Comment: Bootstrap already has grid, panel and navbar features.  It seems reasonable to do it with those, some ng-repeats, and some directives for different types of panels.

Comment: You should ask this in Software Recommendations: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm looking for library not a software for this. softwarerecs.stackexchange.com doesn't seem to be correct issue.

Comment: This is not a proper question for this site.

Answer (score 7):

All theses are your possibilities:

1. [ngPhotoGrid](http://angularscript.com/facebook-like-photo-grid-angularjs-ngphotogrid/)
2. [Seamless Responsive Photo Grid](https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/)
3. [freewall](https://github.com/kombai/freewall) - Using jQuery
4. [Bootstrap Responsive Image Gallery by mobirise](https://mobirise.com/bootstrap-gallery/)
5. [Gamma Gallery](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/06/gamma-gallery-a-responsive-image-gallery-experiment/)

Also read - [An AngularJS directive for Masonry](http://angularscript.com/an-angularjs-directive-for-masonry/)

***ngPhotoGrid example :***

```js
//ngPhotoGrid.js
angular.module("ngPhotoGrid", [])
angular.module("ngPhotoGrid")
  .filter("photoUrlSafe", [
    "$sce", function($sce) {
      return function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(text);
      };
    }
  ])
  .directive('endRepeat', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: "^ngPhotoGrid",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, gridController) {
        if (scope.$last) {
          gridController.notifyDOMReady(element)
        }
      }
    };
  })
  .directive("ngPhotoGrid", ["$templateCache", function($templateCache){

    $templateCache.put("photo_grid.html",
      "<ul class='photo-grid-wrapper' ng-style = 'parentStyle'><li class='grid-cell' ng-repeat= 'image in loadedImages track by $index' ng-style = 'image.cellStyle' ng-click='cellClicked(image)' end-repeat='' ng-attr-data-src='{{image[defaultOptions.urlKey] | photoUrlSafe}}'><img class='grid-cell-image' ng-style = 'image.imageStyle' ng-src='{{image[defaultOptions.urlKey]}}' alt='#'/></li></ul>");

    function linker(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.loadedImages      = [];
      scope.loadedTakenImages = [];
      scope.takenImages       = [];

      // ###OPTIONS
      scope.defaultOptions =  {
                                urlKey          :     "original_url",
                                sortByKey       :     "nth",
                                onClicked       :     function() {},
                                onBuilded       :     function() {},
                                onDOMReady      :     function() {},
                                margin          :     2,
                                maxLength       :     5,
                                isSquare        :     false,
                                buildOnLoading  :     true
                              }

      angular.extend(scope.defaultOptions, scope.gridOptions);

      var IS_SQUARE    = scope.defaultOptions.isSquare;
      var GRID_WIDTH   = element.prop('offsetWidth');
      var MARGIN       = scope.defaultOptions.margin;

      if (!GRID_WIDTH) { // set the default width of parent
        GRID_WIDTH = 250
      }

      scope.parentStyle = { width: GRID_WIDTH + "px", overflow: "hidden", position: "relative", margin: 0, padding: 0 }

      if(IS_SQUARE) {
        scope.parentStyle.height = GRID_WIDTH + "px";
      }

      var commonStyle = {
                      display:        'block',
                      overflow:       'hidden',
                      cssFloat:       'left',
                      cursor:         'pointer',
                      position:       'relative'
                    };

      //callback handler
      scope.cellClicked = function(image) {
        scope.defaultOptions.onClicked(image);
      }

      /**
      * choose images from the url source to build grid
      * take maximum 7 images for best looking
      *------------------------------------------------*/
      scope.chooseImages = function(images) {
        angular.forEach(images, function(image, index) {
          var randNumber; //set the id and nth value for image if does not have
          randNumber                = randomNumber();
          image.id                  = image.id || randNumber;
          image[scope.defaultOptions.sortByKey]  = image[scope.defaultOptions.sortByKey] || randNumber;
        });

        var sortedImages = images.sort(function(a, b) {
          return a[scope.defaultOptions.sortByKey] - b[scope.defaultOptions.sortByKey]
        })

        return sortedImages.slice(0, scope.defaultOptions.maxLength)
      }

      randomNumber = function(max) {
        max = max || 999;
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*max);
      }

      scope.preloadImages = function(images) {
        scope.takenImages = scope.chooseImages(images)

        angular.forEach(scope.takenImages, function(image, index) {
          var img;
          img                     = new Image();
          img.id                  = image.id ;
          img[scope.defaultOptions.sortByKey]  = image[scope.defaultOptions.sortByKey];

          img.onload              = function(loadedImage) {
            scope.loadedTakenImages.push(loadedImage);

            // store the original dimesion of image
            image.naturalWidth    = loadedImage.target.naturalWidth
            image.naturalHeight   = loadedImage.target.naturalHeight

            // build the grid immediatly after the image was loaded
            // building while images loading
            if(scope.defaultOptions.buildOnLoading) {
              scope.buildPhotoGrid();
              setTimeout(function() {
                scope.$apply()
              }, 10)
            }
            
            if(scope.loadedTakenImages.length == scope.takenImages.length) {   
              //trigger build completed handler
              scope.defaultOptions.onBuilded(element)
   
              //grid also can be build after all image loaded
              //all image would be shown correctly, loading time cause poor UX
              if(!scope.defaultOptions.buildOnLoading) {
                scope.buildPhotoGrid()
                setTimeout(function() {
                  scope.$apply()
                }, 15)
              }
            }
            
          };
          img.src = image[scope.defaultOptions.urlKey];
        });
      };

      scope.buildPhotoGrid = function() {
        var firstImage, imageStyle, smallCellHeight,
        smallCellWidth, bigCellWidth, bigCellHeight, cellCount, is2First;

        // get cell style & builded options
        styles          = scope.getCellStyles();
        smallCellHeight = styles.options.smallCellHeight;
        smallCellWidth  = styles.options.smallCellWidth;
        bigCellWidth    = styles.options.bigCellWidth;
        bigCellHeight   = styles.options.bigCellHeight;
        cellCount       = styles.options.cellCount;
        is2First        = styles.options.is2First;

        scope.loadedImages = []
        angular.forEach(scope.takenImages, function(image, index) {
          if (is2First) { //case the grid has 2 image big first
            var bigCellStyle, smallCellStyle;
            bigCellStyle          = angular.copy(styles.big);
            smallCellStyle        = angular.copy(styles.small);
            if (index == 0) {
              bigCellStyle.top    = "0";
              image.cellStyle     = bigCellStyle;
              image.imageStyle = getImageStyle(bigCellWidth, bigCellHeight, image);
            } else if (index  == 1) {
              bigCellStyle.top    = bigCellHeight + MARGIN + "px";
              image.cellStyle     = bigCellStyle;
              image.imageStyle = getImageStyle(bigCellWidth, bigCellHeight, image);
            } else {
              var margin, smallCellIndex;

              // fix the last cell of 2 first was not fit the grid height
              if(index == scope.takenImages.length - 1) {
                smallCellStyle.height = smallCellHeight + MARGIN + "px"
              }

              smallCellIndex      = index - 2;
              margin              = smallCellIndex == 0 ? 0 : MARGIN;
              smallCellStyle.top  = smallCellIndex * smallCellHeight + (margin * smallCellIndex) + "px";
              image.cellStyle     = smallCellStyle;
              image.imageStyle    = getImageStyle(smallCellWidth, smallCellHeight, image);


            }
          } else if (index == 0) { //big cell style
            image.cellStyle = styles.big;
            image.imageStyle = getImageStyle(bigCellWidth, bigCellHeight, image);
          } else if (index != cellCount - 1 || cellCount == 2){ //small cells
            image.cellStyle = styles.small;
            image.imageStyle = getImageStyle(smallCellWidth, smallCellHeight, image);
          } else { //last small cell style (remove redundant margin right or bottom)
            image.imageStyle = getImageStyle(smallCellWidth, smallCellHeight, image);
            image.cellStyle = styles.last;
          }
        })
        scope.loadedImages = scope.takenImages;
      }

      function getImageStyle(cellWidth, cellHeight, image) {
        var imageWidth, imageHeight, curImageWidth, curImageHeight, imgRatio, cellRatio;

        cellWidth  = Math.round(cellWidth);
        cellHeight = Math.round(cellHeight);
        imageWidth  = image.naturalWidth;
        imageHeight = image.naturalHeight;
        imgRatio  = imageWidth / imageHeight;
        cellRatio = cellWidth / cellHeight;

        // when the any image's dimension greater than cell's dimension
        if(cellWidth > imageWidth || cellHeight > imageHeight) {
          if (cellWidth >= imageWidth) {
            return getSmallImagePortraitStyle(cellHeight, cellWidth, imgRatio);
          } else {
            return getSmallImageLandscapeStyle(cellHeight, cellWidth, imgRatio);
          }
        } else { // when the image smaller than the cell in both dimension
          if(imgRatio >= 1) {
            return getSmallImageLandscapeStyle(cellHeight, cellWidth, imgRatio);
          } else {
            return getSmallImagePortraitStyle(cellHeight, cellWidth, imgRatio);
          }
        }
      }

      function getSmallImageLandscapeStyle(cellHeight, cellWidth, imgRatio) {
        var curImageWidth = cellWidth;
        var curImageHeight = Math.round(curImageWidth  / imgRatio);
        if(curImageHeight >= cellHeight) {
          var top = (-1) * Math.round((cellWidth / imgRatio - cellHeight) / 2);
          if(curImageWidth < cellWidth) {
            return { width: "100%", position: "relative", top: top + "px"}
          } else {
            return { maxWidth: "100%", position: "relative", top: top + "px"}
          }
        } else {
          var left = (-1) * Math.round((cellHeight * imgRatio - cellWidth) / 2);
          return { maxHeight: "100%", height: "100%", position: "relative", left: left + "px"}
        }
      }
          
      function getSmallImagePortraitStyle(cellHeight, cellWidth, imgRatio) {
        var curImageHeight = cellHeight;
        var curImageWidth = Math.round(curImageHeight  * imgRatio);
        var top = (-1) * Math.round((cellWidth / imgRatio - cellHeight) / 2);
        var left = (-1) * Math.round((cellHeight * imgRatio - cellWidth) / 2);
        if(curImageWidth <= cellWidth) {
          return { width: "100%", position: "relative", top: top + "px"}
        } else {
          return { maxHeight: "100%", height: "100%", position: "relative", left: left + "px"} 
        }
      }

      /**
      * build cell style for grid
      * @firstRatio   : ratio of the first image in list
      * @secondRatio  : ratio of the second image in list
      * @cellCount    : total cells in grid
      *------------------------------------------------*/
      buildCellStyle      = function (firstImage, secondImage, cellCount) {
        var firstRatio, secondRatio, bigCellStyle, smallCellStyle, lastCellStyle,
            WIDTH_RATE, bigCellWidth, bigCellHeight, smallCellHeight, smallCellWidth, is2First, 
            case2BigImage1, case2BigImage2;

        firstRatio              = firstImage.naturalWidth / firstImage.naturalHeight;

        if (secondImage)
          secondRatio           = secondImage.naturalWidth / secondImage.naturalHeight;
        else
          secondRatio           = 1.5 //fail all cases below

        bigCellStyle            = angular.copy(commonStyle);
        smallCellStyle          = angular.copy(commonStyle);
        lastCellStyle           = angular.copy(commonStyle);
        WIDTH_RATE              = getWidthRate(firstRatio, cellCount);
        case2BigImage1          = firstRatio  > 0.8 && firstRatio  < 1.2 &&
                                  secondRatio > 0.8 && secondRatio < 1.2
        case2BigImage2          = firstRatio >= 2 && secondRatio >= 2

        if(cellCount == 2) { //build style for grid has 2 images and first image has firstRatio > 1

          if(firstRatio >= 1) {
            bigCellStyle.marginBottom = MARGIN;
            bigCellStyle.width    = GRID_WIDTH;
            bigCellStyle.height   = GRID_WIDTH / 2;
            smallCellStyle.width  = GRID_WIDTH;
            smallCellStyle.height = GRID_WIDTH / 2 - MARGIN;
          } else {
            var marginSize              = MARGIN / cellCount;
            bigCellStyle.marginRight    = marginSize;
            smallCellStyle.marginLeft   = marginSize;

            if(IS_SQUARE) {
              bigCellWidth          = Math.floor(GRID_WIDTH / 2) - MARGIN;
              bigCellStyle.width    = bigCellWidth;
              bigCellStyle.height   = GRID_WIDTH;

              smallCellWidth        = Math.floor(GRID_WIDTH / 2) - MARGIN;
              smallCellStyle.width  = smallCellWidth;
              smallCellStyle.height = GRID_WIDTH;
            } else {
              bigCellWidth          = Math.floor(GRID_WIDTH * WIDTH_RATE) - MARGIN;
              bigCellStyle.width    = bigCellWidth;
              bigCellStyle.height   = bigCellWidth;

              smallCellWidth        = GRID_WIDTH - bigCellWidth - MARGIN;
              smallCellHeight       = bigCellWidth;
              smallCellStyle.width  = smallCellWidth;
              smallCellStyle.height = smallCellHeight;
            }
          }
        }

        // add style for first column contain 2 big images, only support for grid has more than 5 cells
        //NOTE: need check when 2 first were same size!!!
        else if (cellCount >= 5 && (case2BigImage1 || case2BigImage2)) {
          var GRID_HEIGHT;
          WIDTH_RATE            = case2BigImage1 ? 1/2 : 2/3;
          scope.parentStyle.position = "relative";
          bigCellStyle.cssFloat = smallCellStyle.cssFloat = lastCellStyle.cssFloat = null;
          bigCellStyle.position = smallCellStyle.position = lastCellStyle.position = "absolute";

          //determine the height of the big cell
          //height == width / 2 if the grid in case2BigImage1
          if(case2BigImage1) {
            bigCellHeight = GRID_WIDTH / 2;
          } else {
            bigCellHeight  = WIDTH_RATE * GRID_WIDTH / firstRatio;
          }

          GRID_HEIGHT               = bigCellHeight * 2 + MARGIN; //margin bottom the first big image
          scope.parentStyle.height  = GRID_HEIGHT + "px";

          bigCellStyle.width        = GRID_WIDTH * WIDTH_RATE - MARGIN;
          bigCellStyle.height       = bigCellHeight;
          bigCellStyle.left         = 0;

          smallCellStyle.width      = GRID_WIDTH - bigCellStyle.width - MARGIN;
          smallCellStyle.height     = Math.floor((GRID_HEIGHT / (cellCount - 2))) - MARGIN;
          smallCellStyle.right      = 0;

          is2First                  = true; //flag this style is has 2 big image style
          lastCellStyle.height      = smallCellStyle.height + MARGIN;

        } else if(firstRatio >= 1) { //build style for grid more than 2 images and first image has firstRatio > 1

          bigCellStyle.marginBottom  = MARGIN;
          smallCellStyle.marginRight = MARGIN;
          var smallCellCount         = cellCount - 1;
          
          if (IS_SQUARE) {
            bigCellStyle.height   = GRID_WIDTH * 2 / 3;
            bigCellStyle.width    = GRID_WIDTH;
            smallCellStyle.height = GRID_WIDTH * 1 / 3 - MARGIN;
          } else {
            bigCellStyle.width    = GRID_WIDTH ;
            bigCellStyle.height   = GRID_WIDTH * 2 / 3;
          }
          smallCellStyle.width  = ( GRID_WIDTH - smallCellCount * MARGIN ) / smallCellCount;
          // determine the height of smallCell below
          if (IS_SQUARE) {
            smallCellStyle.height = GRID_WIDTH - bigCellStyle.height - MARGIN;
          } else if (firstRatio > 1.3 && firstRatio < 1.5) { // 4:3 < firstRatio < 5:3
            smallCellStyle.height     = smallCellStyle.width / firstRatio;
          } else if (firstRatio > 1.5) {
            smallCellStyle.height     = smallCellStyle.width / 1.5;
          } else {
            smallCellStyle.height     = smallCellStyle.width;
          }
          lastCellStyle.height = smallCellStyle.height;
          lastCellStyle.width  = smallCellStyle.width;
        } else { //build style for grid more than 2 images and first image has firstRatio <= 1
          bigCellStyle.marginRight       = MARGIN;
          smallCellStyle.marginBottom    = MARGIN;

          if (IS_SQUARE) {
            bigCellHeight   = GRID_WIDTH;
            bigCellWidth    = GRID_WIDTH * WIDTH_RATE;
          } else {
            bigCellWidth    = Math.floor(GRID_WIDTH * WIDTH_RATE);
            bigCellHeight   = bigCellWidth / firstRatio;
          }

          bigCellStyle.width    = bigCellWidth;
          bigCellStyle.height   = bigCellHeight;

          smallCellCount        = cellCount - 1;
          smallCellWidth        = GRID_WIDTH - bigCellWidth - MARGIN;
          smallCellHeight       = bigCellHeight / smallCellCount - MARGIN

          smallCellStyle.width  = GRID_WIDTH - bigCellWidth - MARGIN;
          smallCellStyle.height = smallCellHeight;
          lastCellStyle.width   = smallCellWidth;
          lastCellStyle.height  = smallCellHeight;
        }

        return {
          big:    bigCellStyle,
          small:  smallCellStyle,
          last:   lastCellStyle,
          options:  {
            firstRatio:       firstRatio,
            // keep these value because ng style need add measured suffix
            smallCellWidth:   smallCellStyle.width,
            smallCellHeight:  smallCellStyle.height,
            bigCellWidth:     bigCellStyle.width,
            bigCellHeight:    bigCellStyle.height,
            cellCount:        cellCount,
            is2First:         is2First
          } //keep these values to style cell image after building style for cell link
        }
      }

      getWidthRate = function(firstRatio, cellCount) {
        if (cellCount == 2) { //build style for 2 images
          if(firstRatio > 1) {
            return 2/3;
          } else {
            return 1/2;
          }
        } else if(firstRatio > 1) { //build style for >= 3 images, first image has firstRatio > 1
          return 1
        } else { //build style for >= 3 images, first image has firstRatio < 1
          return 2/3
        }
      }

      scope.getCellStyles     = function() {
        var firstImage, secondImage, cellCount, buildedStyle;

        firstImage            = scope.takenImages[0];
        secondImage           = scope.takenImages[1];
        cellCount             = scope.takenImages.length;

        if (cellCount == 1) { //build style for only one image
          //@todo need implement!
        } else { //build style for >=2 images
          buildedStyle        = buildCellStyle(firstImage, secondImage, cellCount);
        }

        // remove margin right of last small cell in the bottom
        if(buildedStyle.small.marginRight) {
          buildedStyle.last.marginRight     = 0;
          buildedStyle.last.width           = buildedStyle.small.width + MARGIN;
        }

        // remove margin bottom of last small cell in the right
        if(buildedStyle.small.marginBottom) {
          buildedStyle.last.marginBottom    = 0;
          buildedStyle.last.height          = buildedStyle.small.height + MARGIN;
        }

        // add suffix px for margin and size for ng-style working
        var attrs = ["width", "height", "marginRight", "marginLeft", "marginBottom", "left", "right"];
        angular.forEach(attrs, function(attr, index) {
          if(buildedStyle.big[attr]) {
            buildedStyle.big[attr]   += "px";
          }
          if(buildedStyle.small[attr]) {
            buildedStyle.small[attr] += "px";
          }
          if(buildedStyle.last[attr]) {
            buildedStyle.last[attr]  += "px";
          }
        })

        return buildedStyle;
      }

      //trigger build grid
      scope.$watch("images", function(images) {
        if(images && images.length > 0) {
          scope.preloadImages(images);
        }
      })
    }

    return {
      restrict:       "A",
      templateUrl:    "photo_grid.html",
      scope: {
        images:       "=",
        gridOptions:  "="
      },
      controller: ["$scope", "$element", function($scope, $element) {
        this.notifyDOMReady = function() {
          $scope.defaultOptions.onDOMReady($element)
        }
      }],
      link: linker
    }

  }])





angular.module("ngApp", ["ngPhotoGrid"])
angular.module("ngApp").controller("indexCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){

  //show loading mark while grid is building
  $scope.isBuildingGrid = true;

  // production test
  img1 = {original_url: "http://lorempixel.com/1366/768"};
  img2 = {original_url: "http://lorempixel.com/316/316"};
  img3 = {original_url: "http://lorempixel.com/400/200"};
  img4 = {original_url: "http://lorempixel.com/600/1000"};
  img5 = {original_url: "http://lorempixel.com/600/800"};
  img6 = {original_url: "http://lorempixel.com/800/600"};
  img7 = {original_url: "http://lorempixel.com/800/800"};
  img8 = {original_url: "http://lorempixel.com/900/1000"};

  // // local dev
  // img1 = {original_url: "images/1366x768.jpg"};
  // img2 = {original_url: "images/316x316.jpg"};
  // img3 = {original_url: "images/600x1000.jpg"};
  // img4 = {original_url: "images/900x1000.jpg"};
  // img5 = {original_url: "images/600x800.jpg"};
  // img6 = {original_url: "images/800x600.jpg"};
  // img7 = {original_url: "images/800x800.jpg"};
  // img8 = {original_url: "images/900x1000.jpg"};

  var sources             = [img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6, img7, img8]

  var sources2big            = [{original_url: "http://lorempixel.com/316/316", nth: 1}, {original_url: "http://lorempixel.com/800/800", nth: 2}, img3, img4, img5, img6]

  $scope.rand             = function(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  }

  $scope.clickHandler     = function(image) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(image))
  }

  $scope.buildCompletedHandler = function() {
    console.log ("built completed!")
    $scope.isBuildingGrid = false;
    
  }

  getSelectedSeeds = function() {
    var photoNumbers      = $scope.rand(2, 7)
    var seeds             = []
    var arr               = []
    while(arr.length < photoNumbers){
      var randomnumber    = $scope.rand(1, 8);
      var found           = false;
      for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] == randomnumber ){
          found           = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(!found) {
        arr[arr.length]   = randomnumber;
        seeds.push(sources[randomnumber])
      }
    }
    return seeds;
  }

  $scope.images              = getSelectedSeeds();

  $scope.images2big          = sources2big.slice(0, 7);

  /**
   * Options definitions
   *----------------------*/
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    urlKey      :     "original_url",
    sortKey     :     "nth",
    onClicked   :     function(image) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(image))
                      },
    onBuilded   :     function() {
                        console.log ("built completed!")
                        $scope.isBuildingGrid = false;
                        
                      },
    margin      :     2,
    maxLength   :     5
  }

  /**
   * Options definitions for square example
   *----------------------------------------*/
  $scope.gridOptionsSquare = {
    urlKey      :     "original_url",
    sortKey     :     "nth",
    onClicked   :     function(image) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(image))
                      },
    onBuilded   :     function() {
                        console.log ("built completed!")
                        $scope.isBuildingGrid = false;
                        
                      },
    margin      :     2,
    isSquare    :     true,
    maxLength   :     4
  }
    
  $scope.squareGridGroup = [];

  angular.forEach([1,2,3,4,5,6], function() {
    $scope.squareGridGroup.push(angular.copy(getSelectedSeeds()))
  })


}])
```

```css
/**
* All these styles are not a part of angular module.
*/
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
.small {
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
.content {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.feed-item{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.feed-photos {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.feed-photos.loading::after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.6) url("loader.gif") center center no-repeat;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  position: absolute;

}
.feed-photos.loading .grid-cell-image{
  width: 100%;
}

/**
* It's the part of module
* used to style the border of grid
* included this style if you want to border the grid cell
*/
.grid-cell:after {  
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); /*change this color if you want*/
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      body { text-align: center; }
      .links a { padding: 0 5px ;}
      .active { color: red;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body ng-app='ngApp'>
    <div class='wrapper' ng-controller="indexCtrl">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>ngPhotoGrid Example - 2 bigs first</h1>
      </div>
      <div class='content'>
        <div class="feed-item">
          <div  ng-photo-grid =   ""
                images        =   "images2big"
                grid-options  =   "gridOptions"
                ng-class      =   "{'loading': isBuildingGrid}"
                class         =   "feed-photos">
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class='small'><i>click on image or turn on firebug to see the callback.</i></p>
      </div>

      <div class='footer'>
        <p><a href="https://github.com/jerryc-nguyen/ng-photo-grid" target="_blank">source on github</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Good pointers. Although you're missing an important fact: facebook only shows part of each image. The reason for this is that the grid layout used by facebook "imposes" given resolutions to each picture, and the pictures are very likely to differ from them. After looking further, it looks like facebook "intelligently" finds out which part of each pic is most relevant and position the pic according to this & the expected resolution. Note that there might be other things happening that I have not found out.

Answer (score 3):

There is an easier way to do this by using pure css: `column-count` and `column-width`.

Here's a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/3z73obt0/1/)

And here's the code:

```css
#wrapper {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  column-gap: 10px;
}
#wrapper > div:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin-top:10px;
}
#wrapper > div:nth-child(1) {
  height: 150px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#8ebce5;
}
#wrapper > div:nth-child(2) {
  height: 150px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#3a2313;
}
#wrapper > div:nth-child(3) {
  height: 100px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:peru;
}
#wrapper > div:nth-child(4) {
  height: 100px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#BB3579;
}
#wrapper > div:nth-child(5) {
  height: 100px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#EAC243;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

If you would still prefer using a library, I would suggest having a look at the isotope library to achieve this. (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/).

Here's a codepen of a nice masonry layout made with isotope: http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/mIkhq

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried **ngPhotoGrid**? https://github.com/jerryc-nguyen/ng-photo-grid

> A simple compact photo grid like Facebook in AngularJS with no dependencies.

From looking at its [Examples](http://jerryc-nguyen.github.io/ng-photo-grid/) it looks like what you are looking for.