# Angular - Facebook feed like image grid

Tags: angular, image

I have an application that fetch images from facebook posts. I would like to have a similar image grid display like on Facebook's feed.

[image]

Is there a library/tool in can use in Angular 2+ to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-masonry/ng-photo-grid

These links might help you:

1. http://embed.plnkr.co/h4r4nceA725JeVBvQH7F/
2. http://ignitersworld.com/lab/angulargrid/
3. [Facebook/Twitter Style photos grid style layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36988153/facebook-twitter-style-photos-grid-style-layout)
4. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mikepol/ng-photo-grid
5. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-crystal-gallery