# How to fit images set like facebook in bootstrap css & angular 7

Tags: css, angular7

I want to fit images set like facebook photo albums showing in newsfeed.

When I'm trying this it will show with huge spaces.
here is my code

html code

```
<div class="pCollection">
        <div class="row pCollection-header">
            <div *ngFor="let photo of getPhotos(); let i=index" class="col-md-6">
                <div *ngIf="photos.length > 4">
                    <div  *ngIf="i != 3">
                            <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-img-wrapper">
                                        <img class="card-img-top" (click)="open(i)" src="{{photo.src}}" alt="">
                                         <div class="overlay">
                                            <p *ngIf="i == 3" class="restImages"> + {{photos.length - 4}}</p>
                                         </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                    </div>
                    <div  *ngIf="i == 3">
                            <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-img-wrapper">
                                        <img class="card-img-top" (click)="open(i)" src="{{photo.src}}" alt="">
                                         <div class="overlay">
                                            <p class="restImages"> + {{photos.length - 4}}</p>
                                         </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div *ngIf="photos.length < 5">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-img-wrapper">
                            <img class="card-img-top" (click)="open(i)" src="{{photo.src}}" alt="">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div></div>
```

this is my css code

```
.pCollection-header .col-md-6 {
    padding-left: 0;  
    padding-right:0;  
}


.pCollection {
   overflow: hidden;
}  

.card{
   cursor: pointer;
}

.card-img-wrapper   {
position: relative;
/* background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); */
}
.card-img-wrapper img{
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.overlay{
   position: absolute;
   top: 35%;
   left: 36%;
   z-index: 1000;

}

.restImages   {


   color: #fff;
   font-size: 35px;
   }

@media (min-width: 576px) {
   .restImages {
       font-size: 24px;
   }
 }


@media (min-width: 768px) { 
   .restImages {
       font-size: 24px;
   }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
   .restImages {
       font-size: 35px;
   }
 }


@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
   .restImages {
       font-size: 35px;
   }
}
```

this is the screenshot for this code
[image]

this is the screenshot for what I'm expecting
 [image]

please anyone know how to do this,please help me.I wasted few days for this issue.

Comment: these are 2 columns... first one is col-8 and will show one photo only... 2nd col is col-4 and shows multiple images as per *ngFor - if you make a stackblitz, it'll be quicker to show this also

Comment: @Akber,Thanks alot for your reply. can you please explain what are you talking please.I didn't get what are you saying.

Comment: In the Facebook example which you shared, there div is divided into 2 columns... width of first half is 8 columns (out of 12 columns) and will show one photo only... 2nd half is 4 columns (out of 12 columns) and shows multiple images as per *ngFor - if you make a stackblitz, it'll be quicker to show this also...

Comment: how I decide 1st image contains long height? if it's a small one then this layout will not display like wise.am I correct?
2nd half also same,these photos width and height are not same values

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hkumc6 to explain what I meant... i think you should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36988153/facebook-twitter-style-photos-grid-style-layout

Comment: @Akbar, I checked that,after adding margin to photos,it look like this
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wcgywu
it turned right and right corner photo is not aligned

Comment: @Akber, someone voted this question as not useful,you know why is it?

Comment: I don't have enough privileges to know who voted this down... btw, check my proposed css changes in the answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/gallery/Facebook-like-Photo-Grid-Plugin-With-jQuery-images-grid.html) for this if you want. You can see the [demo](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Facebook-like-Photo-Grid-Plugin-With-jQuery-images-grid/) it's exactly what you want.

Comment: ,Thanks alot for your reply.This is the one I'm finding,but are you think is this plugin can add to angular 7 project.Past day I tried to add jquery plugin,but those plugins not working.Actually I couldn't find a such a way to add jquery on angular project.please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS for the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wcgywu) which you created...

```css
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.paddingReset>div{
  padding:0;
}

.img-responsive-custom{
  max-width: 100%; 
  display:block; 
  height: auto;
}

.left-set>img{
  border-right:2px;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  border-left:2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff;
}

.right-set>img{
border-top:1px;
border-right:2px;
border-left:2px;
border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff;
}

.column9Custom{width:75%;}
.column3Custom{width:25%;}
```

Comment: I added this css code to your photos.then it's showing properly.but if I add my images,then it not showing correctly
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-65ozyk

Comment: do you have any idea regarding to that?

Comment: this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36988153/facebook-twitter-style-photos-grid-style-layout ... if you're stuck, you can always ask here... but please give it a serious go yourself first